# Fetching only few attributes of a document in couchdb

Tags: couchdb

I have a site where I have documents that are around 1MB in size. To avoid any kind of conceptual joins I have put all related data in a single document.

Now I often need to fetch only one or two attributes of a document. Each document has over 10 attributes many of which are pretty large. I can not go on writing views for every single combination of the attributes.

How should I do it ? The only way I see is creating views on the fly and then using those views. OR is there any better method ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Document_Update_Handlers

While it seems strange to call a update feature, couch allows you to return information from the document without updating it. See the xml example.

Here might be an example you could extend:

Add jsonpath to your ddoc,  ( https://github.com/s3u/JSONPath)

```
function(doc, req) { 
    var jsonpath = require('jsonpath');
    var path = req.query.path;
    var target = jsonpath(doc, path);
    var json = JSON.stringify(target);
    var resp = { 'headers' : { 'Content-Type' : 'application/json' }, 'body' : json };
    return [doc, resp]; 
}
```

Comment: The above still holds true, but actually I would recommend using a show function instead. It is almost exactly the same code. Just more the right way.

Comment: And don't forget about list functions: if you're only _querying_ a few predefined attributes but need to _retrieve_ arbitrary combinations of attributes, a list function that returns a JSON object containing only those parts of documents specified by query paramenters is just what you want.

Comment: I have created a bit of a library to make this more fun. see https://github.com/ryanramage/kanso-jsonselect